# PHP ReflectionMethod doesn't return number of parameters

Tags: php, reflection

Here is the code:

```
 public function __call($name, $parameters) {
    if (method_exists($this->_connection, $name)) {
        $refl = new \ReflectionMethod($this->_connection, $name);
        $params = $refl->getParameters();
        print_r($params);
        return 0;
    }
    return parent::__call($name, $parameters);
}
```

Connection is, by the way, connection to Redis server, and it's in an extension.
Why the `$params` is always empty?

Comment: does $refl->getNumberOfParameters() return zero?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you can't use the regular reflection methods on extensions, as they're not written in PHP. There is a [ReflectionExtension](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionextension.php) class that you might be able to use instead.